# Deleting Objects (Reference) in C# DevExpress (Error)

Tags: c#, reference, devexpress

I would like to make DevExpress Turkish. So, I accidentally deleted references in c# DevExpress Project (shown figure). And then uploaded again. But now i get many erorrs. Also , C# toolbox  Please help. The project very important for me. How can i fix this errors ?

Using section :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the usings section to the question.

Comment: `So, I accidentally deleted references in c# DevExpress Project (shown figure).` Can you go back to an old commit in your source repository (git etc) and thus 'undo' your accidental deletion?

Comment: No, I deleted and then upload again same references but project does not know the adding references.

Comment: This is not the correct section. Show the one from BugunYapilacakarl.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do -

- Remove all the DevExpress references from 'References' (yes, again).
- Build the solution (and let it fail).
- Clean the solution (Right Click on Solution & select 'Clean Solution')
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete all the Temporary ASP.Net Files (it's found here mostly - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files)
- Open the Visual Studio and then the solution
- Add the DevExpress references again
- Clean the solution
- Build the solution (and hopefully it won't fail this time!).